# how to call a webservice in umbraco

Tags: web-services, umbraco, umbraco5

I am having an URL like this I need to call this URL from umbraco CMS thia URL is my webservice

```
eg
http://www.mydomain.com/webservices/MyWebservice.asmx/MyFunction
```

But this webservice should only be called through a .net user control after executing some statements 
can anyone share your ideas or link with me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following are the steps....

1) Create a visual studio project Say ServiceClient.

2) Create at user control say ServiceAgnet.ascx.

3) Add a SErvice reference to http://www.mydomain.com/webservices/MyWebservice.asmx/MyFunction

4) Use the service in ServiceAgnet.ascx

5) Publish the code.

6) Put the ASCX in umbraco user control directory.

7) Put the DLL in Bin folder of Umbraco installation.

7) Create a macro using above User Control.

8) Put the macro on page and you can see the websvice being used.

9) Most Important Put the service refernce secion in web.config form you Visual studio project to Umbraco web.config unless it fails.

Hope above helps.

Comment: Didnt noticed that step let me chect it out I think I should call the webservice from the <system.web> tag.But currently I have called the webservice as Add->Service Reference